# Getting collection names in mongodb php

Tags: collections, mongodb, php-mongodb

Here's my db:

```
$db = new Mongo("mongodb://u:pw@server.com:37068/dbname");
```

I want to echo a list/array of collections (the names) on the database.

How can I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use listCollections: http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb.listcollections.php

```
<?php

$db = new Mongo("mongodb://u:pw@server.com:37068/dbname");
$list = $db->listCollections();
foreach ($list as $collection) {
    echo "$collection \n";
}

?>
```

Comment: I mean i need to iterate through these. When I tried `echo json_encode( $list );` it gave me an array of timeout errors.

Comment: $list is an array of MongoCollection which json_encode can't serialize.  You need to iterate through them and call $collection->getName() on each MongoCollection and store those results in a new array and call json_encode on the new array.